# Angular 8 - show/hide row table on click and keep this one already open

Tags: angular, html-table

Having an issue showing and hiding row in table. I am able to open row on the click but I would like :

```
**1- Able to collapse the row when I click again on the row**
**2- If a row is already open and I click on a other row, keep both open**
```

this is my project :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-e3wpvc

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-u4uvvy?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts

Comment: thanks but when I click on the the row nothing happen ..

Comment: It was just a small mistake toggle(i) instead of toggle(t) .. thanks.. but the issue with is when we already have an open row and we open a new one, the data of the new is loaded in the previous .. you can check in you stakckblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-jjm8zo

Here I changed two of your variables to support multiple selection. Also avoiding api calls for sub data of it is done once.

```
  subDatas: Map<number, DataElement[]> = new Map();
  visibleRrowIndex: number [] = [];



  onRowClick(data: DataElement, i: number){
    if(this.visibleRrowIndex.includes(i)){
      // this block executed if row is clicked while open
      this.visibleRrowIndex.splice(this.visibleRrowIndex.indexOf(i));
    } else {
      // this block is execured if row is newly opening
      this.visibleRrowIndex.push(i);
      if(!this.subDatas.has(i)){
        this.loadSubData(data, i);
      }
    }
  }

  loadSubData(data: DataElement, i: number) {
    this.dataService.getDataByDocument(data.document).then((result) => {
      this.subDatas.set(i, result);
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

Comment: yes I tested it.. and seems good .. but I notived that .. **1 : if i open 3 rows and I click on the firts one, all rows are collapsed ..  **2- if I use a backend server, load the subdata one, should be also ok ?

Comment: it is worked, just update this line :       this.visibleRrowIndex.splice(this.visibleRrowIndex.indexOf(i) , 1);